# How to access a csv. date modified value

Tags: python, csv, date, time, save

quick question... I have a piece of python code that reads the content of a csv file into a python dictionary. Does anybody know of a way I can bring the csv 'time/date saved' value into my python code as well?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean getting the last modified time of your CSV file you can get that by using [os.path.getmtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime).    Like:

```py
import os
import time
csv_mod_dttm = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("/path/to/your/file.csv"))
print(csv_mod_dttm)
```

Other times and file specific content is available too.  Just check out the ref link above.

Comment: many thanks, I shall give that a try. Thank you so much